# Prevent jCarousel from showing an image twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

I've integrated the jCarousel plugin in a website and it works really well. However, I still have a problem that has been asked before on StackOverflow ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765022/jcarousel-scroll-shows-same-item-twice ) but hasn't been answered.

The default setting shows three images which is exactly what I need. However I have 8 images in the slideshow and jCarousel generates the sets [1][2][3], [4][5][6] and [6][7][8]. But I like to have the last set [7][8][blank].

I've searched in the documentation and the code but unfortunately my knowledge of Javascript is not big enough to find where to change the code. There is also no notion of a setting which does exactly this.

Links to documentation and code:

Documentation: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/
Code: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/lib/jquery.jcarousel.js

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: I don't think there is such a setting, you may have to modify the script yourself. A simpler solution, can't you just add a blank image at the end, so that you have 9 images in total? That should solve your problem.

Comment: I've thought about that but the number of images changes and the width of the images aren't the same every time so this results in strange behavior. I would have to add a images with the size of the total width minus the size of the other images.